# Download online video to local PC While Watching it

Tags: video, download, video-streaming, buffer

Is it possible to **download** the **video** same time **while watching** it?

> Watching an **online video** also consumes transferring data. That means we have to spend some mega bytes for the size of that video. But it's never   downloaded to local PC **while watching it** and if we want to download it   later, we have to spend more megabytes again for the same video.

Comment: A very open question. The video is of course downloaded to the local machine in order to view it, however it's how the site handles it's temporary data and whether that can be intercepted. It could be as simple as looking for a video file in your temporary files, to literally just receiving small incomplete packets in a completely proprietary codec. Very hard to give a single concise answer I'm afraid.

Comment: Use internet download manager. It shows an icon while playing video, from where you can download any supported video.

Comment: @Biswa: Yes we can download. No problem with that. But it consumes additional data(MB) to download the video. I'm asking whether can't we use that same streaming data(MB) simultaneously for download the video

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC Media Player in order to record the video and audio of a network stream (i.e. YouTube) while watching it.

You could just find the video on YouTube, get the link, and download it while viewing it for the first time by clicking the option "Display the output" after opening the youtube media in the "Convert / Save" menu under "Media".

This is a little bit difficult to get to work though, and longer videos take a longer to download. You have to worry about which codecs your computer is able to use to convert the streaming content into a file format, as well as keeping audio and video synchronized.

Comment: I think i should try this method and response. Thanks,